# Unresolved external symbol while doing createButton opencv visual

Tags: c++, opencv

my kod is simple as fu... ;) and it should be ok, but it is not
here is error text

> Error 2   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl cv::createButton(class std::basic_string,class std::allocator > const &,void (__cdecl*)(int,void *),void *,int,bool)" (?createButton@cv@@YAHAEBV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@P6AXHPEAX@Z1H_N@Z) referenced in function main C:...

```
void on_button(int, void*)
{
}


int main(int argc, const char** argv)
{
createButton("test",on_button);
waitKey(0);
return 0;
}
```

is anyone able to tell me whats wrong here?

Comment: oh dear, you probably forgot to link opencv_highgui. but then, createButton is only available with [qt] (http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/qt_new_functions.html) so you probably can't even use it

Comment: i linked highgui, but it may be the problem. do you know is there any function similiar to createButton, but for visual? so far i did not found any

Comment: there's only createTrackbar() in opencv. that's it. or draw a rect and set a mousehandler on the window

Comment: at first i smiled a little but then i realized its in fact smart idea ;) thanks a lot, have a good night!

Answer (score 2):

You are not linking library or are not including source file where createButton is defined.

Comment: im pretty sure i included all what i need
fe following this tutorial http://bikramhanjra.blogspot.com/2013/04/opencv-button-highgui.html
there is only one file included, which i did

Comment: @user3183211 Well, compiler is not so sure - that is the meaning of error message you are getting.

Comment: yeah i know, but still do not what i supposed to do
i included all what i needed, did everything like in few tutorials in web and got that error :/ that code cant be more simply

Comment: @user3183211 because the error is not in the code, but in the project/makefile settings. If you are using some library, you need to link against it - I think this part is missing.